# spring boot websocket api 404 not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws, spring-websocket

In my spring boot app, I'm getting `404` error on the client side when I try to connect to the `ws` endpoint.

client side code

```
let wsUri = "ws://localhost:8080/chat"
let websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

spring config

```
package coffee.web;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addHandler(chatServer(), "/chat");
   }

   @Bean
   public ChatServer chatServer() {
       return new ChatServer();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the request is handled by dispatcher servlet as normal http request. so you need to add @Controller annotation to the WebSocketConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@Controller
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer
```

Answer (score 1):

i was getting 404 error then i have added the controller and then i was getting 403 as you are getting, 403 is like access restriction , so i have removed CSRF filter for that end point and then it is working. i hope it helps